# How to forcefully copy a file from Hdfs to linux file system?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

For the command, `-copyFromLocal` there is an option with `-f` which will forcefully copy the data from Local file system to Hdfs. Similarly with `-copyToLocal` option I tried with `-f` option but, it didn't work. So, can anyone please guide me on that.

Thanks,

Karthik

Comment: maybe simply remove the file locally before using `-copyToLocal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such `-f` for `copytolocal`

```
$ hadoop fs -help

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options]

    [-appendToFile <localsrc> ... <dst>]

    [-cat [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]

    [-checksum <src> ...]

    [-chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...]

    [-chmod [-R] <MODE[,MODE]... | OCTALMODE> PATH...]

    [-chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] PATH...]

    [-copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] <localsrc> ... <dst>]

    [-copyToLocal [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]

    [-count [-q] <path> ...]

    [-cp [-f] [-p | -p[topax]] <src> ... <dst>]

    [-createSnapshot <snapshotDir> [<snapshotName>]]

    [-deleteSnapshot <snapshotDir> <snapshotName>]

    [-df [-h] [<path> ...]]

    [-du [-s] [-h] <path> ...]

    [-expunge]

    [-get [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]

    [-getfacl [-R] <path>]

    [-getfattr [-R] {-n name | -d} [-e en] <path>]

    [-getmerge [-nl] <src> <localdst>]

    [-help [cmd ...]]

    [-ls [-d] [-h] [-R] [<path> ...]]

    [-mkdir [-p] <path> ...]

    [-moveFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]

    [-moveToLocal <src> <localdst>]

    [-mv <src> ... <dst>]

    [-put [-f] [-p] <localsrc> ... <dst>]

    [-renameSnapshot <snapshotDir> <oldName> <newName>]

    [-rm [-f] [-r|-R] [-skipTrash] <src> ...]

    [-rmdir [--ignore-fail-on-non-empty] <dir> ...]

    [-setfacl [-R] [{-b|-k} {-m|-x <acl_spec>} <path>]|[--set <acl_spec> <path>]]

    [-setfattr {-n name [-v value] | -x name} <path>]

    [-setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path> ...]

    [-stat [format] <path> ...]

    [-tail [-f] <file>]

    [-test -[defsz] <path>]

    [-text [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]

    [-touchz <path> ...]
```

Pls refer this for more info  [Hadoop hdfs commands](http://hadooptutorial.info/hdfs-file-system-commands/)